# how to send unlimited php mail from godaddy(shared host) without any mail plan ?

Tags: php

I have tried sending mail from gmail and other share hosting mail server and its works as expected But Now my requirement is sending mail from go-daddy mail server.whenever i try to send mail it shows gives me error failure sending mail after sending 500 emails.

Comment: Pretty sure you're neither able nor allowed to do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the services offered by GoDaddy, not a question about programming.

Comment: I believe it is prohibited to send mass message on shared hosting. If you want to send mass message, you need to use dedicated email service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic or non-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, if you are sending mail too frequently and heavily, it will detect your account as spammer and suspend as well.

Gmail also not allow you to send mails in bulk, it will result as timed out.

Instead you can choose an SMTP service, such as [Mandrill](http://www.mandrill.com/), which gives you limit to send 200 email in a day.

Answer (score 0):

for sending unlimited mail from script i have to use PHPMailer classes with default SMTP. i tried it can send more then 1000 mail (unlimited) in inbox.